# Pros/cons with this Angular project setup

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I´m new to web development and went trough thus [Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio). Everything works grate. Now I wanted to use Angular as front end,

- Is is better to have the Angular project in a separate project or to have both the ASP.net core and Angular 8 in the same VS Solution? any pros/cons with this?
- Can Angular app be added to above Visual Studio ASP.NET Core project using angular cli command "ng new ClientApp", any pros/cons with this?

I don't think this question/answers is opinion based because there is a right/wrong way to do this

Comment: .NET CORE has an [angular template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) that provides you with a **ready to start** solution. You could generate the template and see how it's done. webpack is not that easy to configure on your own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: if you add both front-end and backend in the same project you have to use webpack or same kind of module bundler to do so.

- ng command wont work in webpack (and it isn't easy to configure) so you have to do everything manual like creating component
- Project will take more time to compile than single project.

2: i couldn't understand your second point.